# Making payment application using PayPal

Tags: paypal

We are building an application, which is going to help different organizations to collect from members a member monthly fee. The fee is not the same and needes to be calculated. 
In order to allow a member to be a member for next month, he needs to pay the monthly fee. We are building an application which will help organization to support collection of the fee (online application). 
When the user enters application then he may calculate the fee and be transferred to a paypal in order to pay. 
Our application will fill the necessary fields in Paypal application as:
- How much shall be paid
- To whom email adres -of his organization
- And other information needed.

Do you think it can work (programmaticaly even when a member does not have a Paypal account?

We need to get the info asap. I know that tere are two methods (IPN and PDT). Teh PDT gives very quick feedback but it may be lost if there are some transfer technical problems.

We do not see here a way for collection our provision, which is here quite small 
The problem is that the money are paid directluy to organization and wee need an iformation about the payment (which shall be sent automatically from beneficjent account).
As far as I know the orgnization can set their account the way that when the payment arrives then the info will be sent to some url address, which the organization may place (this mean to our WEBsite).

Marek Staniewski

Answer (score 0):

IPN and PDT are not payment methods.  Those are post-transaction processing features that PayPal provides.

To actually process payments and split the money up between multiple accounts the way it sounds like you're talking about you should look at the [Adaptive Payments APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/), specifically the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API.